# How to javascript my button onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my js:

```
function showMore() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".yt-card.yt-card-has-padding").style.padding = "15px";
}

function showLess() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".yt-card.yt-card-has-padding").style.padding = "15px 15px 10px 15px";
}
```

Why does my button with js function not work?

One of two buttons:

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-expander yt-uix-expander-head yt-uix-expander-body" type="button" onclick="showLess();">
```

Comment: That is youtube HTML :D so it will be hard

Comment: What does not work? Are you sucessfully invoking the function. Is the display "none" not set..?

Comment: does it step into the function showLess??

Comment: Try to remove the `;` in `onclick="showLess();"`

Comment: Without ; it is still not working :/

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` does not return a single element. It returns an `HTMLCollection` that you will need to index before you can set styles.

Comment: hold on does it go into the function or not?????

Comment: My browser console shows: showMore and showLess is not defined? What?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak that will work.. it just is not needed if there 2 function in the onclick the ; is used

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes that is true. Do you know how to make it work? :D

Comment: What are you trying to show or hide? I do not see the code for the element of the item that you are trying to act upon.

Also, I believe you have an unnecessary `;` in the `onclick` attribute, which if you remove should provide better results.

Comment: @KennethSalomon Removing the semi-colon should have literally no effect.

Comment: It is hard to explain because I am making my own style sheet for YouTube and the code shown here ^ is only a small part.

Comment: Check your console in Firefox. If you have a javascript error somewhere else it will not find anything defined after that.

Comment: Should I change showMore to this: 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".yt-card.yt-card-has-padding");
   x[0].style.padding = "15px";?

Comment: Make sure you include the javascript in the html page or put a link to the javascript file. Or copy the functions below into the console, click the button with the onclick and check if that does anything. good luck.

Comment: I have tried all possibilities for javascript - now it is included into html site.

Comment: In tampermonkey there was the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection` rather than a single element. You need to treat this as though it is an `Array` in order to set styles on the individual elements:

```
function showMore() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "block";

    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-card yt-card-has-padding");
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].style.padding = "15px";
    }
}

function showLess() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "none";

    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-card yt-card-has-padding");
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].style.padding = "15px 15px 10px 15px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could the downvoter at least give me a reason why you think this answer is wrong or misleading?

Comment: This function is nice. I know but that doesn't change anything. The button onclick still doesn't work :(

Comment: Even without changing the paddings the script doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you putting the functions?

Comment: new one: GET https://www.youtube.com/gen_204?feature=watch-show-more-metadata net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: I have my functions in tampermonkey now. It is matching: *://www.youtube.com/*

Comment: If you're using Tamper Monkey to inject code, you may have to declare the functions as `window.showMore = function () { ... };` and similarly for the `showLess` function.

Comment: What about using [`myButton.addEventListener('click', function () { ... });`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach code to a click handler? It's probably a better way of trying to do what you're doing.

Comment: But how to attach it to YouTube button? YouTube button has only classes.

Comment: You attach the click handler to the buttons you added to the page rather than using `<button ... onclick="showLess();">`.

Comment: Look: document.addEventListener("click", pokazWiecej);

function pokazWiecej() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "block";
}

document.addEventListener("click", pokazMniej);

function pokazMniej() {
    document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "none";
}

Comment: Do you have any idea how to precise which button i want to change? It is youtube button so it is hard to make it by myself.

Comment: That addeventlistener is working but i need to precise which func to which button will be attached

Comment: Okay. I made that! <3 Thanks to you. Is there any way to give you +rep on this site? :D It is my first day.

Comment: I did that little bit different than you in that fiddle but it is still thanks to you :D (I haven't seen your fiddle when I done my func :) )

Comment: You know... it is the same as yours but based on classes. <3 One more time thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` should not have `.` class selector before each class. Change the fullstops to spaces, and sort through the returned array variable to edit the padding of the element.

```
function showMore() {
   document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "block";
   var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-card yt-card-has-padding");
   classes[0].style.padding = "15px";
   classes[1].style.padding = "15px";
  } 

function showLess() {
   document.getElementById("watch-description").style.display = "none";
   var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("yt-card yt-card-has-padding");
   classes[0].style.padding = "15px 15px 10px 15px";
   classes[1].style.padding = "15px 15px 10px 15px";
  }
```